# How do I move giant boulders?

Tags: zelda-link-between-worlds

I know that I can lift and move small rocks, but there are giant boulders around Hyrule and Lorule that I can't seem to move. Bombs and the hammer don't seem to work, unless I am doing something wrong.

How do I move these giant boulders?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To move the large rocks, you will need the [*Titan's Mitt*](http://www.linkshideaway.com/a-link-between-worlds/gear-guide/#TitansMitt), which are found inside the [*Desert Palace Dungeon*](http://www.linkshideaway.com/a-link-between-worlds-walkthrough/desert-palace/).

To get to that dungeon, you will need to have access to Lorule, and you will need to have either rented or bought the [*Sand Rod*](http://www.linkshideaway.com/a-link-between-worlds/items/#SandRod). In order to do *that*, you will need to have saved [*Sage Osfala*](http://www.linkshideaway.com/a-link-between-worlds/gear-guide/#SageOsfala) in the [*Thieves' Hideout dungeon*](http://www.linkshideaway.com/a-link-between-worlds-walkthrough/thieves-hideout/) located in *Thieves' Town*, Lorule's version of *Kakariko Village*.

Answer (score 2):

I think he means the GIANT cracked boulders in Lorule, which you can only destroy by claiming the Big Bomb Flower south of Thieves Town (East of Lorule's Rupee Fever game).  You get to drag it through various screens, but it will explode if enemies mess with it.  You can keep going back for new Big Bombs without having to pay.

Comment: He said: "there are giant boulders around ***Hyrule*** and Lorule". Those boulders you speak of are found only in Lorule. But it's good you mentioned those. +1

Comment: Those aren't the ones I mean, but that is good to know regardless!

Answer (score 0):

For the cracked boulders (the ones that sometimes have rupees inside), you just need to own and upgrade the hammer.  It will smash them.

Answer (score -4):

To get the power gloves , all you have to do is go to rosoes house ( the miners house ) after completing the eastern palace and speak to him, 
He will then give them to you . For an extra bonus when you have the power gloves , go outside and crush all the rocks then he will give you a prize. This games the best!